# How to set Z index when using WPF DrawingContext?

Tags: c#, wpf, canvas, drawing, z-index

How to set `Z-Index` for a drawing object when using `DrawingContext.DrawXXX()` methods?

Answer (score 5):

The object that was drawn last will have a higher Z index. You can't change index of an already drawn objects. The only way is to draw in another order.

If you are using WPF (as you placed that tag), you can use, for example, Canvas control. Then you just create shapes you need like

```
Polyline obj = new Polyline(); //...
// ... set properties of obj
```

and add them to Canvas UIElementCollection:

```
yourCanvasName.Children.Add(obj);
//or
yourCanvasName.Children.Insert(i, obj);
```

First items of that collection will have higher Z index. You will also get advantages in that way: no need to redraw on window changes, can anytime move objects and change order.

Comment: I talk about DrawingContext class and its methods such as DrawRectangle or DrawGeometry. They draw directly on a canvas.

Comment: @brain_pusher, with DrawingContext you can't solve your problem.